# woocommerce and is_user_logged_in() if not redirect to homepage

Tags: php, login, plugins, membership

I am currently using woocommerce and would like to redirect none logged in users to the home page, however i am having a little trouble determining where i should implements this

I have done research and determined that using the is_user_logged_in() i can see if the user is logged in.

I tryed implementing in the woocommerce/woocommerce-functions.php

```
// When default permalinks are enabled, redirect shop page to post type archive url
    if (is_user_logged_in() && isset($_GET['page_id']) && $_GET['page_id'] > 0 && get_option( 'permalink_structure' )=="" && $_GET['page_id'] ==     woocommerce_get_page_id('shop') ) :
        wp_safe_redirect( get_post_type_archive_link('product') );
        exit;
    endif;
```

but it still allows the page to be visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want to insert your code at the top of the page templates for the Woo pages you would like the redirect to affect rather than the functions file. So for example if you want to redirect users when they try to access an individual product page you could put it at the top of the plugins->woocommerce->templates->single-product.php page.

When editing templates though I would recommend making a copy and placing it in your theme directory, so that when Woo updates it will not override any changes you made. So for the example I gave above (applied to my theme). I would copy single-product.php and place it in the themes->agency file and then make the changes to that file, there. Your theme will then always use that file before the one in the Woo template file.

Comment: thank you do you know which page would have to be modified to redirect users who view the initial shop page?

Comment: Since the shop page is actually a loop, you could put a hook in your functions.php file. copy this in and let me know if it works. http://pastie.org/4830106 . I have some strange stuff on my shop page (I essentially deleted it) so I can't test it myself. If it doesn't work I'll fix it.

Comment: hmm after adding that to my themes functions.php file the entire site stopped working. was i supposed to add it to woocommerce functions file?

Comment: Sorry I made a lazy syntax error, delete that and try this http://pastie.org/4830960

Comment: Okay, I went ahead and tested this code and it definitely works : http://pastie.org/4831059 . Paste that in the functions.php file

Comment: bugz - Did this work?

Comment: If this worked could you check this answer..

Comment: I disagree with inserting that code at the top of the page templates for the Woo pages. [`template_redirect` action hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) should be used.

Answer (score 1):

First off never edit other peoples plugins or core wordpress files.

Also use braces rather than pretty formatting, as pretty formatting breaks IDE code highlighting, brace matching, syntax checkers and other handy tools

So put this code:

```
// When default permalinks are enabled, redirect shop page to post type archive url
if (is_user_logged_in() && isset($_GET['page_id']) && $_GET['page_id'] > 0 && get_option( 'permalink_structure' )=="" && $_GET['page_id'] ==     woocommerce_get_page_id('shop') ) {
    wp_redirect( get_post_type_archive_link('product') );
    die();
}
```

Either in:

- the top of functions.php
- A dedicated plugin
- On the Init hook call

Comment: thanks for the recommendation, i will try adding this to the functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Use the code `functions.php`:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_login_redirect');

function wc_login_redirect( $redirect_to ) {
     $redirect_to = 'https://www.example.com/';
     return $redirect_to;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and provide some explanation. Dumping a code snippet without explanation is a bad answer.